# Biographical informations on Igor Ado

Tags: biographical-details, reference-request

Ado's Theorem is a very reelvant result in Lie theory (every finite-dimensional Lie algebra is isomorphic to a matrix Lie algebra).

I've been, however, unable to find anything more than very basics information on who is the mathematician that proved it. Igor Ado (1910-1983), student of Chebotaryov, graduated in Kazan University in 1935. And basically that's all.

Does anyone know of some more related informations?

Comment: There is a one-page memorial article from 1984 at http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=ivm&paperid=8696&option_lang=rus. Click where you see "PDE файл".  It is in Russian.

Answer (score 6):

In: D.V. Anosov, M.I. Monastyrskii, M.A. Soloviev, Nas ostalos' tak malo... (So few of us remained...), Istoriko-Matematicheskie Issledovaniya 7 (2002), 166-189 (in Russian) (the periodical is available in many places, for example [here](http://old.mathedu.ru/journals-collections/)), Ado is mentioned in passing. It is claimed that Chebotarev failed to create an algebraic school in Kazan' due to bureaucratic/political obstacles; Ado was unable to find a suitable employment in academia, has left pure mathematics (what is apparent from his list of publications), and has switched to numerical mathematics.

Answer (score 5):

There is the one-page obituary mentioned by Keith Conrad. V. Gubarev and me have uploaded an English translation to the arXiv, see [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.08361). Furthermore I have tried to provide a more detailed English wikipedia page for Igor Dmitrievich Ado, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Igor_Dmitrievich_Ado). I am grateful to Yurii Neretin for providing me with information.